Need help on Oracle Join
I have 2 tables:
Department



DEPT
FLAG




D1
Y


D2
Y


D3
Y


D4
Y



Employee



EMP
DEPT
FLAG




EMP1
D1
Y


EMP1
D2
Y


EMP2
D1
Y


EMP2
D2
Y


EMP2
D3
Y


EMP3
D3
Y


EMP4
D2
Y


EMP4
D3
Y



I need to display like:



EMP
DEPT
FLAG




EMP1
D1
Y


EMP1
D2
Y


EMP1
D3
N


EMP1
D4
N


EMP2
D1
Y


EMP2
D2
Y


EMP2
D3
Y


EMP2
D4
N


EMP3
D1
N


EMP3
D2
N


EMP3
D3
Y


EMP3
D4
N


EMP4
D1
N


EMP4
D2
Y


EMP4
D3
Y


EMP4
D4
N



I'm unable to get 'N' records from all employee. If I pass single employee with outer join, then I can get. But if I pass all employees I'm getting only 'Y' records.

I dont know why table formation is not happening for other 2 tables. Adding an image.

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question and Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. both apply here. Also, it's impossible to explain why your SQL is not working as you'd like, because you haven't posted any SQL here at all. SO is not a free code writing service.

On a side note: A table should not be called Employee, when it doesn't contain employees (i.e. one row per employee).

This is what a PARTITIONed OUTER JOIN is for:
SELECT e.emp,
       d.dept,
       COALESCE(e.flag, 'N') AS flag
FROM   department d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN employee e
       PARTITION BY (e.emp)
       ON (d.dept = e.dept)

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE Department (DEPT, FLAG) AS
SELECT 'D1', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D2', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D3', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D4', 'Y' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Employee (EMP, DEPT, FLAG) AS
SELECT 'EMP1', 'D1', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EMP1', 'D2', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EMP2', 'D1', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EMP2', 'D2', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EMP2', 'D3', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EMP3', 'D3', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EMP4', 'D2', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EMP4', 'D3', 'Y' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



EMP
DEPT
FLAG




EMP1
D1
Y


EMP1
D2
Y


EMP1
D3
N


EMP1
D4
N


EMP2
D1
Y


EMP2
D2
Y


EMP2
D3
Y


EMP2
D4
N


EMP3
D1
N


EMP3
D2
N


EMP3
D3
Y


EMP3
D4
N


EMP4
D1
N


EMP4
D2
Y


EMP4
D3
Y


EMP4
D4
N



fiddle

You need a cross join approach to generate an intermediate table of all departments and employees.  Then left join that to the table on the right to get the result you want.
SELECT e.emp, d.dept, COALESCE(t.flag, 'N') AS flag
FROM dept d
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT emp FROM emp) e
LEFT JOIN emp t
    ON t.dept = d.dept AND
       t.emp = e.emp
ORDER BY e.emp, d.dept;

